# How to access [Authorize] controller actions using HttpClient with Bearer token? Getting 401 "The audience is invalid"

Tags: identityserver4, dotnet-httpclient, asp.net-core-2.1, bearer-token, audience

There are four clients within the application:

1. angular.application - *resource owner*
2. identity_ms.client - *webapi app (.net core 2.1)*

   - IdentityServer4 with AspNetIdentity
   - *AccountController* with shared actions to register users, reset password etc.
   - *UserController* with secured actions.
     The *Data* action of the *UserController* has an `[Authorize(Policy = "user.data")]` attribute
3. ms_1.client - *webapi app (.net core 2.1)*
4. request.client - *added specially to send requests from ms_1.client to identity_ms.client's UserController to get some user data.*

I'm requesting clients using Postman:

1. http://localhost:identity_ms_port/connect/token to get *access_token*
2. http://localhost:ms_1_port/api/secured/action to get some secured data from ms_1
3. http://localhost:identity_ms_port/api/user/data to get some secured user data from *identity_ms*

Everything is working fine.

Also, *ms_1* service has a secured action requesting *http://localhost:identity_ms_port/api/user/data* using `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`.

```cs
// identity_ms configuration
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(/*cors options*/);

    services
        .AddMvc()
        .AddApplicationPart(/*Assembly*/)
        .AddJsonOptions(/*SerializerSettings*/)
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    services.Configure<IISOptions>(iis =>
    {
        iis.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Windows";
        iis.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
    });

    var clients = new List<Client>
    {
        new Client
    {
            ClientId = "angular.application",
            ClientSecrets =
            {
                new Secret("secret".Sha256())
            },
            AllowedScopes = { "user.data.scope", "ms_1.scope", "identity_ms.scope" },
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword
    },
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "ms_1.client",
            ClientSecrets =
            {
                new Secret("secret".Sha256())
            },
            AllowedScopes = { "user.data.scope", "ms_1.scope" },
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials
        },
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "identity_ms.client",
            ClientSecrets =
            {
                new Secret("secret".Sha256())
            },
            AllowedScopes =
            {
                "user.data.scope",
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile
            },
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit
        },
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "request.client",
            AllowedScopes = { "user.data.scope" },
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
            ClientSecrets =
            {
                new Secret("secret".Sha256())
            }
        }
    };
    var apiResources = new List<ApiResource>
    {
        new ApiResource("ms_1.scope", "MS1 microservice scope"),
        new ApiResource("identity_ms.scope", "Identity microservice scope"),
        new ApiResource("user.data.scope", "Requests between microservices scope")
    };

    var identityResources = new List<IdentityResource>
    {
        new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
        new IdentityResources.Profile()
    };

    services
        .AddAuthorization(options => options.AddPolicy("user.data", policy => policy.RequireScope("user.data.scope")))
        .AddIdentityServer()
        .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
        .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(identityResources)
        .AddInMemoryApiResources(apiResources)
        .AddInMemoryClients(clients);

    services
        .AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Audience = "identity_ms.scope";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.Authority = "http://localhost:identity_ms_port";
        });

    services.AddSwaggerGen(/*swagger options*/);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseMiddleware<CustomMiddleware>();
    app.UseIdentityServer();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseCors("Policy");
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMvc(/*routes*/);
    app.UseSwagger();
}

// ms_1.client configuration
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(/*cors options*/);

    services
        .AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(/*SerializerSettings*/)
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    services
        .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            options.Audience = "ms_1.scope";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.Authority = "http://localhost:identity_ms_port";
        });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseMiddleware<CustomMiddleware>();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseCors("Policy");
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMvc(/*routes*/);
    app.UseSwagger();
}

// ms_1.client action using HttpClient
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(ViewModel model)
{
    //...
    using (var client = new TokenClient("http://localhost:identity_ms_port/connect/token", "ms_1.client", "secret"))
    {
        var response = await client.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("user.data.scope");

        if (response.IsError)
        {
            throw new Exception($"{response.Error}{(string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.ErrorDescription) ? string.Empty : $": {response.ErrorDescription}")}", response.Exception);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response.AccessToken))
        {
            throw new Exception("Access token is empty");
        }

        var udClient = new HttpClient();

        udClient.SetBearerToken(response.AccessToken);
        udClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var result = await udClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:identity_ms_port/api/user/data");
    }
    //...
}
```

I've tried the following:

1. To retrieve *access_token* from the request to *ms_1* Authorization header and use it to access *user/data*.
2. To get new *access_token* to access *user/data* with it.
   See `public async Task<IActionResult> Post(ViewModel model)` code within the code block.

In both cases, I've got the correct token which I can use to request both *secured/action* and *user/data* actions from Postman, but HttpClient is getting Unauthorized response (401).

[Response headers screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xR1CJ.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Set audience in your api config to “MS1 microservice scope” maybe, also please post your token sample (raw encoded preferably)

Comment: Hi, @VidmantasBlazevicius thanks for a reply. Did you mean change this `.AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Audience = "identity_ms.scope";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.Authority = "http://localhost:identity_ms_port";
        });` into this `.AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Audience = "MS1 microservice scope";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.Authority = "http://localhost:identity_ms_port";
        });`?

Answer (score 0):

In your client code with `HttpClient` you are not requesting any scopes for the API therefore the token that is issued by Identity Server 4 will not contain the API as one of the audiences and then subsequently you will get 401 from API.

Change your token request to ask for the API scope as well.

```
var response = await client.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("user.data.scope ms_1.scope");
```